# MYSQL weighted average by other column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the weighted average of 5 columns in a mysql table. I am successfully doing it by fetching all rows and in php calculate it.

However as my table now has over 2.000.000 rows and query is not seldom 20.000 rows it runs slooowly.

Basically, if the row has a `weight_index of 1 it should the row:column-worth is 0.5` and if it has `weight_index=2, row:column-worth is 1.`

Then calculate the average for column a, b, c, d and e.

```
+----+----------+---+---+---+----+---+--------------+
| id | store_id | a | b | c |  d | e | weight_index |
+----+----------+---+---+---+----+---+--------------+
|  1 |     1    | 2 | 3 | 4 |  5 | 6 |       1      |
+----+----------+---+---+---+----+---+--------------+
|  2 |     1    | 3 | 4 | 1 |  2 | 0 |       2      |
+----+----------+---+---+---+----+---+--------------+
|  3 |     1    | 4 | 3 | 1 | 10 | 5 |       3      |
+----+----------+---+---+---+----+---+--------------+
|  4 |     1    | 2 | 3 | 4 |  5 | 6 |       2      |
+----+----------+---+---+---+----+---+--------------+

$weight_index = [1 => 0.5, 2 => 1, 3 => 1, 4 => 1, 5 => 1, 6 => 0.7];
```

I am currently using Mysql.

EDIT 1:

What I am trying get is weighted avg for each column (a-e) (not rows). The cells worth is defined by weight_index.

*Similar to AVG(a) but the rows with weight_index 1 is valued at 0.5...*

```
CREATE TABLE `items`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `a` INT NOT NULL,
    `b` INT NOT NULL,
    `c` INT NOT NULL,
    `d` INT NOT NULL,
    `e` INT NOT NULL,
    `weight_index` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
); 

INSERT INTO `items`(
    `id`,
    `user_id`,
    `a`,
    `b`,
    `c`,
    `d`,
    `e`,
    `weight_index`
)
VALUES(NULL, '1', '2', '3', '6', '3', '4', '1'),(NULL, '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '3', '2'),(NULL, '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '2'),(NULL, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another table with the weight values. Join with it and multiply the averages by the weight.

```
CREATE TABLE weights (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    weight FLOAT
);
INSERT INTO weights (id, weight) VALUES
(1, 0.5), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 0.7);

SELECT t.store_id, 
    SUM(w.weight * t.a)/SUM(w.weight) AS a, 
    SUM(w.weight * t.b)/SUM(w.weight) AS b, 
    SUM(w.weight * t.c)/SUM(w.weight) AS c, 
    SUM(w.weight * t.d)/SUM(w.weight) AS d, 
    SUM(w.weight * t.e)/SUM(w.weight) AS e
FROM your_table AS t
JOIN weights AS w ON t.weight_index = w.id
GROUP BY t.store_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, however this will produce the weighted average per row. I need it per column.

Comment: I thought that might be it, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: This will indeed produce the average per column but not the weigted average as it only multiplies the value, making the value of a weight_index 1-row only smaller and thus influencing the total avg even more.

A row with weight 1 is worth the same as two rows with weight 0.5.

Comment: https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/weighted-average-calculator.html has a good online calculator for it.

Comment: I thought that was the definition of weighted average, didn't know about dividing by the sum of the weights. I've updated the answer.